# Turn On and Off Numlock Key using C# (.Net Framework 4.7)

Tags: c#, toggle, .net-framework-version, num-lock

I have tried with InputSimulator and InputSimulatorPlus package also.

- Require Condition as below

  ```
  if current_Number Odd: turn Off NumLock Key
  ```

  ```
  if current_Number Even : turn On NumLock Key
  ```

```
bool numLockEnabled = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock);
  for (int current_Number = 0; current_Number  < 10; current_Number ++)
  {
    // Toggle the NumLock key
        if (current_Number % 2 == 0)
        {
            // NumLock is currently on, turn it off
            SendKeys.SendWait("{NUMLOCK}");
       }
       else
       {
            // NumLock is currently off, turn it on
           SendKeys.SendWait("{NUMLOCK}");
      }
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
      Console.WriteLine($" current_Number Value {current_Number} , numLockEnabled {numLockEnabled} , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock)  {Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock)}");
 }
```

- Current Output

```
current_Number  Value  0 , numLockEnabled True , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) True
current_Number  Value  1 , numLockEnabled True , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) True
current_Number  Value  2 , numLockEnabled True , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) True
...
current_Number  Value  9 , numLockEnabled True , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) True
```

- Require Output

```
current_Number  Value  0 , numLockEnabled True , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) False
current_Number  Value  1 , numLockEnabled True , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) True
...
current_Number  Value  9 , numLockEnabled True , Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) True
```

Comment: 0 is even. If you want to turn off CapsLock for 0, you will need to modify the condition to `if (current_Number % 2 == 0 && current_Number != 0)`, if that's what you're asking. Or you may need to set the state before running that loop, if *that's* what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The NumLock key is turned off when the current number is odd and turned on when the current number is even. The `Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock)` method is used to check the current state of the NumLock key. The `SendKeys.SendWait()` method is used to send a key press and wait for the key to be released.

```
bool numLockEnabled = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock);
            for (int current_Number = 0; current_Number < 10; current_Number++)
            {
                // Toggle the NumLock key
                if (current_Number % 2 == 0)
                {
                    // NumLock is currently on, turn it off
                    bool isNumLockOn = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock);
                    SendKeys.SendWait(isNumLockOn ? "NUMLOCK" : "{NUMLOCK}");
                }
                else
                {
                    // NumLock is currently off, turn it on
                    bool isNumLockOn = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock);
                    SendKeys.SendWait(isNumLockOn ? "{NUMLOCK}" : "NUMLOCK");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine($"current_Number Value {current_Number}, numLockEnabled {numLockEnabled}, Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock) {Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock)}");
            }
```

Comment: Its printing "NUMLOCK" each time when the status changed.